# Javascript deep inheritance and the super constructor

Tags: javascript, constructor, super, extends

I'm trying to figure out how super really works in JavaScript.
I have an idea but I'm not sure of it's exactitude so I need some help.

```
class A {

}

class B extends A {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
}

class C extends B {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
}

new C
```

In the above code the **'new' operator creates an object and links it to the constructor C's prototype**, constructor C's hidden property 'thisArg' now points to the newly created object

```
+---------------------+
|   function object   |
+---------------------+
| - code              |
+---------------------+
| - outerScope        |
+---------------------+
| - thisArg           |
+---------------------+
| - [[Prototype]]     |
+---------------------+
| + prototype         |
+---------------------+
| + length            |
+---------------------+
| + name              |
+---------------------+
```

N.B. The hidden property thisArg can be altered at each function call, implicitly (with access operators '.' and '[]'), explicitly (with .call, .apply, .bind methods) or with the 'new' operator

Lexical environment's 'this' reference will then point to whatever functions hidden property thisArg  is pointing at

Back to the process. **The constructor C gets executed then the super passes up the newly created object to the B constructor**, constructor B's hidden property thisArg  now points to the newly created object

same happens with the constructor B, **it gets executed and the super passes up the newly created object to the A constructor where the construction starts**

When A finishes the construction it passes the object down to B

Then B adds more slots to the structure and passes down to C

Finally C ends the construction and returns the constructed object

So basically, the newly created object first bubbles up from constructor to constructor and then trickles down?

Comment: Basically yes. Have you read the `super` section in [How does the "this" keyword work?](/a/3127440/4642212) and the [specification](//tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-super-keyword)? It’s worth pointing out that when doing `new C`, `this` inside the constructors is an instance of `C` (never `A` or `B`), and `this` is only accessible after the last `super` call in the chain.

Comment: @SebastianSimon - Actually, no. The object isn't created until `A` is called. The above is close(ish) for the old way using `function`, but not `class`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder That’s what I meant with _“`this` is only accessible after the last `super` call in the chain”_. _If and when_ the constructed object exists, it is an instance of `C`. Hope this is clear enough…

Comment: @SebastianSimon - Right -- but the explanation above says `this` is created before `C` is called, which is incorrect.

Comment: *"N.B. constructors hidden property 'this' not to be confused with 'this', a member the lexical environment created by a function"* I don't know what you're trying to say there. `this` only has one meaning in JavaScript, there aren't two different ones.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder 'this' within the lexical environment is a mere parameter. It's argument is provided by the function object's 'this', a hidden property, you may call it thisArg

Comment: @Slev7n - This may be a terminology misunderstanding or something. Functions (including constructors) don't have a "hidden 'this' property." [Here's a list of the internal slots of function objects](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ordinary-and-exotic-objects-behaviours.html#sec-ecmascript-function-objects). `this` is a binding held in (non-arrow) function environment records and module environment records. There is a different thing called `thisArgument`, a parameter of the...

Comment: ...[`[[Call]]` operation](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ordinary-and-exotic-objects-behaviours.html#sec-ecmascript-function-objects-call-thisargument-argumentslist). But that's not `this`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's not how it works with `class`. The construction parts of it would be close to correct with the old `function`-based setup, but `class` works slightly differently in this regard.

When you do `new C`, the object isn't created until the `A` constructor is called. Here's what happens:

1. `new` calls `C`'s [[[Construct]]](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ordinary-and-exotic-objects-behaviours.html#sec-ecmascript-function-objects-construct-argumentslist-newtarget) internal method with `new.target` set to `C`.

   1. Any code in `C` prior to `super()` runs. `this` is inaccessible at this point.
   2. `C`'s code calls `B`'s [[Construct]] (via `super()`) with `new.target` still set to `C`.

      1. Any code in `B` prior to `super()` runs. `this` is still in accessible.
      2. `B` calls `A`'s [[Construct]] (via `super()`) with `new.target` still set to `C`.

         1. Since `A` is the base constructor, `A`'s [[Construct]] creates the object, setting its prototype from the `prototype` property of `new.target` (which is `C`).
         2. Any code in the `A` constructor runs, and has access to `this`.
      3. Any code in `B` after `super()` runs (and has access to `this`).
   3. Any code in `C` after `super()` runs (and has access to `this`).
2. The object created by `A` is the result of the `new` expression.

(I'm skipping over some minor details above for clarity.)

This is how the `class` construct ensures that the new object is initialized *in order* from the base constructor (`A`) to the first derived constructor (`B`) and the finally the `new` target (`C`). That way, `A` has access to the new object first, followed by `B`, followed by `C`.

More in in the specification link above.

Comment: FWIW, I go into this stuff in detail in Chapter 4 of my recent book *JavaScript: The New Toys* covering everything in ES2015-ES2020. Links in my profile if you're interested.